# I am trying to access contents inside each class tag which is inside each header tag in python using beautiful soup

Tags: python

```
<h3>Most Actives</h3>
<table class="wsod_dataTable wsod_dataTableBigAlt">
<h3>Gainers</h3>
<table class="wsod_dataTable wsod_dataTableBigAlt">
<h3>Losers</h3>
<table class="wsod_dataTable wsod_dataTableBigAlt">
```

This is the code that I have right now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
url = 'https://money.cnn.com/data/hotstocks/'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

#The class ='cnnBody_Left wsodContent'is the total of 3 h3 tags.
#name = allbody.findAll('h3')-I am finding all the 3 header tags and storing as list.
#class_='wsod_dataTable wsod_dataTableBigAlt'-finds only the contents of the first header tag-Most Actives.

allbody = soup.find('div',class_='cnnBody_Left wsodContent')
name = allbody.findAll('h3')
contents=allbody.find('table',class_='wsod_dataTable wsod_dataTableBigAlt')
```

Now,I am able to access class of only Most actives .But I want to access class inside Gainers and Losers.

What I tried.

```
#for each header ,I am trying to access class contents.

for i in range(len(name)):
    alltab = name[i].allbody.find('table',class_='wsod_dataTable wsod_dataTableBigAlt')
    print(alltab)
```

Output:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: You could change your find to findAll for the table as well

Comment: I tried that.did not work out.displaying as none

Comment: You might want to print the contents of `soup` to make sure it actually contains the tables you're interested in.

Comment: I tried with contents if the soup.Still giving the same output